# How to get blob object from chrome.scripting.executeScript in js chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I try to return from chrome.scripting.executeScript because i need to extract the audio from the page. I need to store it in a variable in the main program.

I inject the script in the following function and need to get the audio after 10 seconds :

```
function startRecording(tab) {
    console.log("startRecording : " + tab.id)
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: { tabId: tab.id },
        function: captureAudio,
    },(res) => { 
        console.log(res)
        recordedAudio = res.result
    },
    ).then(()=>{console.log("Record launched !")});
}
```

Here is the function injected on the chrome tab:

```
async function captureAudio() {
    try {
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
      const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
      const audioChunks = [];
  
      // Démarre l'enregistrement lorsque le MediaRecorder reçoit des données
      mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
        audioChunks.push(event.data);
      };
  
      mediaRecorder.start();
  
      // Arrête l'enregistrement après 10 secondes
      setTimeout(() => {
        mediaRecorder.stop();
      }, 10000);
  
      // Lorsque l'enregistrement est arrêté, crée un Blob audio
      mediaRecorder.onstop = () => {
        const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, { type: 'audio/wav' });
        // const audioURL = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
        // console.log("Audio enregistré :", audioURL);
        // chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ message: "recordURL", audioURL : audioURL });
        return audioBlob
      };
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Erreur lors de la capture audio :", error);
    }
  }
```

I tried to use Promises but got stuck. Is there any way to clean code this ?

Comment: The commented out code with createObjectURL is correct, but you need a listener for the message which will use `fetch` + `blob()` on this URL. Alternatively, use `return new Promise` constructor explicitly in captureAudio and `resolve(audioURL)`.

Comment: Chrome serialized your message by JSON.stringify method. JSON doesn't support blob.
send blob buffer as array and then contruct arrayBuffer or covert into Base64

Comment: @Anilkumar Tryed it and it worked thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added this code to send blob through chrome.runtime

```
const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, { type: 'audio/wav' });
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (event) => {
                const audioData = event.target.result; // This is an ArrayBuffer
                // Send the audio data as an array to the background script
                chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ message: "recordURL", audioData: Array.from(new Uint8Array(audioData)) });
            };
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(audioBlob);
```

Then received it in the background listener:

```
case "recordURL":
            const audioData = new Uint8Array(request.audioData);
            const audioBlob = new Blob([audioData], { type: 'audio/wav' });
            console.log("Received audio data as a Blob:", audioBlob);
            break;
```

Worked for me i'm receiving the blob after the 10 seconds of recording.